# Facebook Messenger Checkbox not authorized app

Tags: facebook

I use the exact same code that is presented in the Facebook Documentation

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId     : '<?php echo FB_APP_ID; ?>',
        xfbml     : true,
        version : 'v2.6'
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('messenger_checkbox', function(e) {
         console.log("messenger_checkbox event");
         console.log(e);
         if (e.event == 'rendered') {
             console.log("Plugin was rendered"); 
         } else if (e.event == 'checkbox') {
             var checkboxState = e.state;
             console.log("Checkbox state: " + checkboxState);
         } else if (e.event == 'not_you') {
             console.log("User clicked 'not you'");
         } else if (e.event == 'hidden') {
             console.log("Plugin was hidden");
         } 
     });

     function confirmOptIn(unique) {
        FB.AppEvents.logEvent('MessengerCheckboxUserConfirmation', null, {
            'app_id':'<?php echo FB_APP_ID; ?>',
            'page_id':'<?php echo FB_PAGE_ID; ?>',
            'user_ref': unique
        });
    }

<div class="fb-messenger-checkbox" origin="{origin_url}" page_id="<?php echo FB_PAGE_ID; ?>" messenger_app_id="<?php echo FB_APP_ID; ?>" user_ref="<?php echo $unique; ?>" prechecked="true" allow_login="true" size="large"></div>
```

When I access the page using my account, which is the app administrator, I have no problem rendering the plugin. When I use another account, which is not ad app administrator the Console.log gave me "Plugin was hidden" because the LoginStatus answer not_authorized. 
Reading the documentation it was supposed to be rendered despite the authorization of the app (the opt-in was the authorization). Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: _“Is there anything I'm missing?”_ - probably just the box right on top of the documentation page …? _“When your Facebook app is in Development Mode, plugin and API functionality will only work for admins, developers and testers of the app that have a valid session. After your app is approved and public, it will work for the general public.”_

Comment: The app is approved and public. It's a month that is no longer in development mode!

Comment: And that other user is properly logged in at the time?

Comment: Yes of course. I've tried logging out the user and the plugin appears as it is supposed to, with no user logged. Next login, the plugin is hidden again